# Query formation from JSON object in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I had a requirement like, I need to form a query based on JSONB object parameter and returns its output.

JSONB parameter contains Table name, where clause details, Column value to be returned form a table.

Below is the sample format of JSONB where getjsontesterabledata is the function which takes JSONB as parameter.

```sql
select getjsontesterabledata('{"MODULE": "TEST", 
    "TEST_INFO": {
        "AGGREGATE_OP": "", 
        "RESULT_ATTRIB_NAME": "TESTER_VALUE", 
        "CONDITIONAL_ATTRIBS": [
            {"VALUE": "98842", "ATTRIBUTE": "TEST_ID", "CONDITION_OP": "="},
            {"VALUE": "DRIVE", "ATTRIBUTE": "TEST_NAME", "CONDITION_OP": "="}]
}}');
```

In above JSONB param, MODULE is table name , AGGREGATE_OP is like SUM, AVG ... , CONDITIONAL_ATTRIBS are like where clause.

From the above JSONB parameter, Query formation should be like

```sql
select TESTER_VALUE
from test
where TEST_ID = 98842 and TEST_NAME = 'DRIVE';
```

and this query output should be returned.

Here i am stuck at forming a Query from JSONB Parameter specifically in forming a where clause. I need help on this.

Please note that PostgreSQL version is 12.15.

Answer (score 1):

Basically here it is. Pls. note the formation of the `where` clause and `coalesce`-ing the text to `true` if there is no data for "CONDITIONAL_ATTRIBS".

Please also note that this is a *SQL injection nightmare* and only makes *some* sense if the input parameter data do not come from user input.

```sql
create or replace function getjsontesterabledata(j jsonb)
returns text language sql as  
$$
select
'select ' || (j->'TEST_INFO'->>'RESULT_ATTRIB_NAME') || '
 from '   || (j->>'MODULE') || '
 where '  || coalesce (
 (
   select string_agg(format('%s %s %L', (ca->>'ATTRIBUTE'),(ca->>'CONDITION_OP'),(ca->>'VALUE')), E'\n  and ')   
   from jsonb_array_elements(j -> 'TEST_INFO' -> 'CONDITIONAL_ATTRIBS') ca
 ), 'true') 
$$;

select getjsontesterabledata('{"MODULE": "TEST", 
    "TEST_INFO": {
        "AGGREGATE_OP": "", 
        "RESULT_ATTRIB_NAME": "TESTER_VALUE", 
        "CONDITIONAL_ATTRIBS": [
            {"VALUE": "98842", "ATTRIBUTE": "TEST_ID", "CONDITION_OP": "="},
            {"VALUE": "DRIVE", "ATTRIBUTE": "TEST_NAME", "CONDITION_OP": "="}]
}}'::jsonb);
```

The result is

```sql
select TESTER_VALUE
from TEST
where TEST_ID = '98842'
  and TEST_NAME = 'DRIVE'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a loop using `jsonb_array_elements(data_json->'TEST_INFO'->'CONDITIONAL_ATTRIBS')`.

> jsonb_array_elements expands the top-level JSON array into a set of
> JSON values.

```
-- FUNCTION: public.getjsontesterabledata(text)

-- DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS public.getjsontesterabledata(text);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.getjsontesterabledata(jsontext text)
    RETURNS text
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    COST 100
    VOLATILE PARALLEL UNSAFE
AS $BODY$
DECLARE
    query_text text;
    w record;
    data_json jsonb;
    count_loop int;
BEGIN
    query_text := '';
    count_loop:= 1;
    data_json := jsontext::jsonb;       
    query_text := concat('select ', data_json->'TEST_INFO'->>'RESULT_ATTRIB_NAME', ' from ', data_json->>'MODULE');
    
    for w in       
           select jsonb_array_elements(data_json->'TEST_INFO'->'CONDITIONAL_ATTRIBS') as col
    loop 
        if count_loop = 1 then
            query_text := concat(query_text, ' where ', w.col->>'ATTRIBUTE', w.col->>'CONDITION_OP', '''', w.col->>'VALUE', '''');
        else
            query_text := concat(query_text, ' and ', w.col->>'ATTRIBUTE', w.col->>'CONDITION_OP', '''', w.col->>'VALUE', '''');
        end if;
        
        count_loop:= (count_loop + 1);
    end loop;
RETURN query_text;
END
$BODY$;

select getjsontesterabledata('{"MODULE": "TEST", 
    "TEST_INFO": {
        "AGGREGATE_OP": "", 
        "RESULT_ATTRIB_NAME": "TESTER_VALUE", 
        "CONDITIONAL_ATTRIBS": [
            {"VALUE": "98842", "ATTRIBUTE": "TEST_ID", "CONDITION_OP": "="},
            {"VALUE": "DRIVE", "ATTRIBUTE": "TEST_NAME", "CONDITION_OP": "="}]
}}');
```

You can see this function working in [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/1Or5f5lD).

**Some resources used:**

[Postgresql looping through query results](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-RECORDS-ITERATING)

> Using a different type of FOR loop, you can iterate through the
> results of a query and manipulate that data accordingly.

```
[ <<label>> ] FOR target IN query LOOP
     statements END LOOP [ label ];
```

[Postgresql json functions documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html)

> json -> text → json
>
> jsonb -> text → jsonb
>
> Extracts JSON object field with the given key.
>
> '{"a": {"b":"foo"}}'::json -> 'a' → {"b":"foo"}

> json ->> text → text
>
> jsonb ->> text → text
>
> Extracts JSON object field with the given key, as text.
>
> '{"a":1,"b":2}'::json ->> 'b' → 2

[Postgresql create function documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/16/sql-createfunction.html)

[Postgresql concat documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/16/functions-string.html)

> concat ( val1 "any" [, val2 "any" [, ...] ] ) → text
>
> Concatenates the text representations of all the arguments. NULL
> arguments are ignored.
>
> concat('abcde', 2, NULL, 22) → abcde222